# Just starting and struggling

Tags: php

I am trying to code a basic website as starter test for me and am struggling. It sort of a blog

It has a form and a textarea, the user types in the textarea, and it passes the value to another php page. Where it gets printed as a test.

But it does not get printed. Some help to get me started would be useful. Thanks in advance

```
<form method="Post" action="testit.php" name = "myform">
<textarea name="blogtext" rows="15" cols="50">
</textarea>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit Blog"><p>
</form>
```

and the php file is

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome to you
<?php
$name = $_POST["blogtext"]; 
print $name
?>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: @MikeW PHP doesn't mind a missing semicolon before `?>`

Comment: Are you getting the "Welcome to you" part?

Comment: Do you have this on a server like WAMP, or MAMP?

Comment: Do a `view source` on your testit.php results page. If you see raw PHP code there, then your server is misconfigured and/or not running PHP. If you don't see any php code at all, then php is running, but something is breaking your form and $_POST['blogtext'] is empty/not set.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly on my PC

Comment: Are you running it on a server, url like `http://localhost/whatever.php` or did you just double click the file on your desktop?

Comment: It works fine in my system too.